# Comparing two numbers in DOS not working

Tags: variables, if-statement, compare, dos

```
@echo off
set f = 100
set g = 100
IF f EQU g @echo yes
```

does nothing. What is the problem here?
It seems like the simplest of things
thanks in advance

Oliver

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do like this:

```
    @echo off
    set f=100
    set g=100
    if %f%==%g% echo yes
```

Comment: I'd still use EQU instead of ==.